# struct node * void expected identifier or '(' before 'void'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return-type, function-declaration

There is a function like this. I took this error expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
How to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
struct node * void ekleSirali(struct node * r,int x){
     if(r==NULL){
        r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r->next=NULL;
        r->x =x;     
        return r;  
     }
```

I don't know whether I should write struct.

Comment: Get rid of `void`. The function returns `struct node *`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, in C you [don't have to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: Sidenote: `r=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` can be simplified to `r = malloc(sizeof *r);`

Comment: Also, if `if(r==NULL)` is false, what do you return then?

Comment: And be careful when you assign to local argument variables. If you don't actually use the pointer that `ekleSirali` returns, your code calling the function will cease to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type specifier `void` is redundant and invalid in this context. Write

```
struct node * ekleSirali(struct node * r,int x){
```

That is the function return type can be either `void` (if the function returns nothing) or `struct node *` (if the function returns a pointer of the type `struct node *` as shown in your code snippet).